# Centralize messages in properties file in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have multiple Extjs projects, and each of them have common messages (e.g. the confirmation / warning messages for alert dialog). I would like to centralize all these messages into a file (e.g. properties file). Please tell me how to implement this in Extjs.

Comment: use separate js file. have one object for each js file. in that object declare your properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Sencha CMD [package](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/cmd_packages/cmd_creating_packages.html) to hold common stuff for your projects. Include that package in each project's `app.json` file:

```
"requires": [
    "my-common",
   // other packages
],
```

Put the messages in a singleton:

```
Ext.define('MyCommon.Messages', {
    singleton: true,
    foo: 'Bar'
    // .....
```

Use it in your projects:

`alert(MyCommon.Messages.foo)`